# how can i write the exact area by using integration which that f(x)=sqrt(x+1)+0.25 on function

Tags: c++, math

i found estimated area by using Simpson's 1/3 rule so i want function that found the exact area using f(x)=sqrt(x+1)+0.25

```
float Simpson(float a, float b, int n,float data[],float I, float J,float simpson)
{
    float A;
    //loop
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (i%2!=0)
        {
            I=I+f(data[]);
        }
    }

    //loop
    for(int i=2;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if (i%2==0)
        {
            J=J+f(data[]);
        }
    }

    simpson=(b-a/n*3)*(f(a)+(4*I)+(2*J)+f(b));
    cout<<"The Value of integral under the enterd limits is by usin simpson's rule: "<<endl;
    cout<<simpson<<endl;

    return A;
}
```

Comment: Judging from the `cout << simpson << endl;`, this `C++` code, not `C#`; change the tag.

Comment: than you  i  change it

Comment: You'll have to calculate the integral function by hand. Is this what you need? If not, please clarify.

Comment: no , not by hand i want to calculate it in function and call that function after that  calculate error in the estimation of the area is given by the formula  |exact area - estimated area|

Comment: Ok, so you'll need a library capable of symbolic integration and evaluation. There are a few open source ones. Writing such a lib is quite a big effort and cannot be addressed in a single SO answer. Sorry.

Comment: Also, please note that the exact integral cannot be always calculated, and that's when numerical integration really comes handy. Instead of the actual error, maybe you could use an error estimator?

Comment: so how can i found the error estimator? without finding the exact area

Comment: the easiest way is to compute area with `n=16`, then `n=32`, then `n=64`,... and approximate/extrapolate the result for really big `n`  (ideally in limit `n -> +infinity`) ... where `n` is number of segments you divide the integration range ...